# Is a limited space-time hierarchy theorem correct?

Tags: time-hierarchy

Is a limited (deterministic) space-time hierarchy theorem correct?
For example, we have a limitation of $O(n^2)$  space then:
can we find problems that can be solved in $O(n^k)$ time and $O(n^2)$ space, but that have no algorithms that run in time $O(n^{k-1})$ and $O(n^2)$ space?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38675